# problems with beamerboxesrounded and beamerarticle

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I am trying to convert a beamer presentation (which cointains usage of the environment `beamerboxesrounded` and works fine) into an article using the package `beamerarticle`, but I get the message

> Environnment beamerboxesrounded undefined

This is the code that does not work:

```
%\documentclass[Palatino, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % usually not needed (loaded by default)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum,wrapfig,xcolor}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\useoutertheme{infolines}

\usetheme{Singapore} % NO

\xdefinecolor{oiB}{rgb}{0.22,0.52,0.72}

\setbeamercolor{disc ques body}{fg=oiB}

\newcommand{\dq}[1]{
    \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[shadow = false, lower = disc ques body]{}
        #1
    \end{beamerboxesrounded}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\dq{\lipsum[1]} 

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

It does work fine if I replace the first three lines with

```
\documentclass[Palatino, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

%\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe you could show us what you have done? Something we could compile on our side and see what's not working?

Comment: You are right. I have edited the question.

Comment: Page 127 of the `beamer` user guide (version 3.58) explicitly mentions that the `beamerboxesrounded` environment is not available in `article` mode.

Comment: I was about to say it. Here is [the doc](https://mirrors.chevalier.io/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So, could I replace it with something similar?

Comment: Have a look at the `tcolorbox` package which offers much flexibility for box creation and styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide two different definitions of `\dq` for different beamer modes.

As your beamercolourbox does not have a background colour or shadow, it seems just changing the text colour would be enough to replicate it for article mode:

```
%\documentclass[Palatino, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % usually not needed (loaded by default)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum,wrapfig,xcolor}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\useoutertheme{infolines}

\usetheme{Singapore} % NO

\xdefinecolor{oiB}{rgb}{0.22,0.52,0.72}

\setbeamercolor{disc ques body}{fg=oiB}

\mode<presentation>{
  \newcommand{\dq}[1]{
    \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[shadow = false, lower = disc ques body]{}
        #1
    \end{beamerboxesrounded}
  }
}
\mode<article>{
  \newcommand{\dq}[1]{
    \textcolor{oiB}{#1}
  }
}



\mode<all>



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\dq{\lipsum[1]} 

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```